# [__NSCFNumber rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000005f53

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, geocoding, cllocation

I'm trying to convert my lat long into address using method:

```
#pragma mark:convert latLong to address
-(void)getMerchantAddress:(NSDictionary *)dict
{

    double lata = [[dict valueForKey:@"user_lat"] doubleValue];
    double longa = [[dict valueForKey:@"user_long"] doubleValue];

    NSLog(@"%f",lata);
    NSLog(@"%f",longa);

    CLLocation *LocationAtual = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:lata longitude:longa];


    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:LocationAtual completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
     {
         if(placemarks && placemarks.count > 0)
         {
             CLPlacemark *placemark= [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
             NSArray *lines = placemark.addressDictionary[ @"FormattedAddressLines"];
             NSString *addressString = [lines componentsJoinedByString:@","];
             _usrtAddressLbl.text = addressString;
             _userAddressLbl.text = addressString;
         }
     }];
}
```

my app crash @ point

```
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:LocationAtual completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
```

Error showing:

```
[__NSCFNumber rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000005f53
```

How can I resolve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is printed using NSLog ?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya its showing lat long in correct formate

Comment: Did . you check that  Is completion block executes ?

Comment: app crash after [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation.... completion block not execute.

Comment: Try one thing create `CLLocationCoordinate2D` with lat and long and in LocationAtual pass  CLLocationCoordinate2D.lat and long

Comment: tried but same issue.. :(

Comment: Then only I .  doubt your lata and longa  otherwise your code is okay . just check [[dict valueForKey:@"user_lat"] class]  in NSLog for all variables

Comment: The error message is quite clear: Somewhere a string (`NSString`) is expected but a number (`NSNumber`) is passed. Use the debugger. Set breakpoints and watch the variables. And don’t use `valueForKey` unless you can explain why KVC is explicitly needed.

Comment: Error indicates you are using a NSString method on a NSNumber. Please, check if your data are strings?

Comment: @DixitAkabari dat is in string but I convert it into double as u can see my code above.

Comment: CLLocation * LocationAtual = [[CLLocation alloc]init];
LocationAtual.coordinate.latitude = [@"-56.6462520" floatValue];
LocationAtual.coordinate.longitude = [@"-36.6462520" floatValue];

Comment: @DixitAkabari Already tried not worked for me :(

Comment: @V-Dev Could you Please show your lata and long value ? and use objectForKey instead of valueForKey.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this its working for me**

```
-(void)getMerchantAddress:(NSDictionary *)dict
{


    float lata = [[dict objectForKey:@"user_lat"] floatValue];
    float longa = [[dict objectForKey:@"user_long"] floatValue];

    CLGeocoder *ceo = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
    CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:lata longitude:longa]; //insert your coordinates

    [ceo reverseGeocodeLocation:loc
              completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                  CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                  if (placemark) {

                      NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark);
                      //String to hold address
                      strAddress = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
                      NSLog(@"addressDictionary %@", placemark.addressDictionary);

                  }else {

                  }
              }
     ];
}
```